# How to call a JSON Method in iOS

Tags: json, ios, asihttprequest

There is a JSON call which when i call via curl like below:

> curl -H
>   "Content-Type:application/json" -H
>   "Accept:application/json"  -d
>   "{\"checkin\":{\"message\":\"this is a
>   test\"}}"
>   http://gentle-rain-302.heroku.com/checkins.json

I get this result:

> {"checkin":{"created_at":"2011-01-29T13:52:49Z","id":3,"message":"this
>   is a
>   test","updated_at":"2011-01-29T13:52:49Z"}}

But when i call in my iPhone App like below:

```
- (void)doCheckIn:(NSString *)Str
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inStore-settings.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];

    NSString *appURL = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"apiurl"];
    appURL = [appURL stringByAppendingString:@"checkins.json"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];
    [request setPostValue:@"{\"checkin\":{\"message\":\"test\"}}" forKey:@"message"];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSLog(response);
    }
}
```

I get a result saying :

> "The change you wanted was rejected
>   (422)"

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of appURL in the end? Also, are you sure you are correctly using the setPostValue: method? It appears to be a bit off to me since you want the entire post body to be `{\"checkin\":{\"message\":\"test\"}}` and it looks like you might be setting that as the value for `message`.

Comment: @raidfive: the appURL has "http://gentle-rain-302.heroku.com/checkins.json" and i even tried: "[request setPostValue:@"This is a test message" forKey:@"message"];" Nothing works !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your curl command, I don't think you want to be doing http multipart post, which the `ASIFormDataRequest` is specifically set to handle. You just want to set the post body of a request to your json string. Try using the normal `ASIHTTPRequest` class and adding data to the post body via a method like `appendPostData:` or the like. This should build the appropriate HTTP request for you.

Comment: I haven't messed with this library before, to be honest. I was just examining the south from their site http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code worked:

```
- (void)doCheckIn:(NSString *)Str
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inStore-settings.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];

    NSString *appURL = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"apiurl"];
    appURL = [appURL stringByAppendingString:@"checkins.json"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appURL]];
    [request appendPostData:[@"{\"checkin\":{\"message\":\"test by Zuzar\"}}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you mean `piece` and not `peace`.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try setting the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers in your `ASIFormDataRequest` instance?

Comment: Remember to click the √ next to my answer if it works out for you.